# Using itextsharp check if adding element will create new page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Hi I am generating a PDF file (for a contract). The content is dynamic and I don't know exactly how many pages will be generated. At the end of the document there is a "signatures" section. It could happen that section to be alone on the page. I want to check if that happen to move the previous section to that new page as well.

Let me clarify with pictures. I want if a case like Image 1 happens then the document to be transformed to something like Image 2.

Image 1:
[image: Image 1]

Image 2:
[image: Image 2]

And if a scenario as in Image 3 happens it is perfectly okay to stay that way.

Image 3:
[image: Image 3]

I am using ITextSharp. Could you give me any clue how this could happen?

Comment: Please post your question based on the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Instead of attaching a document, reveal the expexted value so that you can take more people attention.

Comment: could you give me example of your statement, what should be changed?

Comment: Instead of adding a link to your image, you can directly add an image so people will not need to click to link and open the image.

Comment: I changed the image links to inline images, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure what all of this has to do with the Code of Conduct? I changed the image links to inline images. I'm not sure if it is easier to read now, but it is not worse either, I guess.

Comment: Vale, have you considered putting the previous paragraph and the signature line into a table (without border lines or anything) which you don't allow to break?

Comment: Thank you mkl, that worked perfectly and was totally the desired result. Put both paragraphs in a table in 2 cells on 2 rows and set the KeepTogether property of the table to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) found the solution.

I put both paragraphs in 2 row **table**, set the **KeepTogether** property of the table to **true** and hid the borders of the table.

```
Document pdf = new Document();
var previousParagraph = new Paragraph();
/* fill content of previousParagraph*/
var signHere = new Paragraph();
/* fill content of signHere*/

var signatureTable = new PdfPTable(1)
{
    KeepTogether = true,
    WidthPercentage = 100f
};
signatureTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

signatureTable.AddCell(previousParagraph);
signatureTable.AddCell(signHere);

pdf.Add(signatureTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine page size,  the coordinate of the last placed element and the dimensions of your new elements.

If the sum of the height of the new elements exceeds the dimensions of the page when placed at the coordinate adjacent to the last placed element then a new page would be created.

Using math you can find the difference by keeping the total amount of remaining space of the page as a variable and decrmeneting it e.g by the height of newly added elements as you place elements.

You will then know how much space you have left on the page and when adding new content will cause another page to appear.

Keep in mind headers footers and page margins effect the area of the page also.

There may also be some methods on the Document or Page objects which you can use for this or even to create you own extension method to achieve this would be quite trivial given one of the existing objects provided by the iTextSharp API